# Effect of Zero Check on a Ship Repair Spare Parts Required

Tags: mongoose-traveller-2

Using Mongoose Traveller Core Rulebook Update 2022, on page 159.

To repair your ship's Critical Hit damage is a Average Engineer/Mechanical 8+ check, but the table on spare parts required does not have a zero.
That is, if your roll success of 8 how much spare parts do you need?